# Add custom data type records via web service in NetSuite

Tags: c#, netsuite

I have created `C#` application that has reference to `NetSuite` web service. Now I can create simple records in `NetSuite` database. For example I can create Task:

```
                var task = new Task();
                task.externalId = "123";
                task.timedEvent = true;
                task.timedEventSpecified = true;
                task.message = "my message";
                task.reminderType = TaskReminderType._popupWindow;
                task.reminderTypeSpecified = true;
                task.title = "my title";
                task.startDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2);
                task.startDateSpecified = true;
                task.endDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
                task.endDateSpecified = true;
                try
                {
                    var resp = Service.add(task);
                    if (!resp.status.isSuccess)
                    {
                        Log.Info("OK")
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error("err");
                }
```

Now I have created custom data type `Webinar` arroding to [article](https://www.fmtconsultants.com/how-to-create-custom-records-in-netsuite-step-by-step-instructions-part-i/). I can add souch type records from NetSuite web interface. But how to add souch records by using NetSuite web service like I did with `Task` sample?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a CustomRecord object, add your custom fields to it and add that to NetSuite through the web services.

Make sure that the scriptIds of the custom fields that you add to the CustomRecord, match the id's of the custom fields on your record(as found on the web UI).